# Can `(?=regex)` and `(?!regex)` be used in the middle of a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, can `(?=regex)` and `(?!regex)` be used in the middle of a regular expression, or they must be used at the end of a regular expression? If they can be used in the middle, what's the meaning of it?

Comment: Why do you ask for their meaning in the middle of a regex specifically? Do you assume they have a different meaning at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?=…)` and `(?!…)` (lookaheads) asserts that the string after it matches/does not match the sub-regex, without actually consuming them. They can appear anywhere. For example

```
^(\d)(?!\1)\d+$
```

matches

```
12345
67890
```

but not

```
11234
55678
```

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for detail.